# Extend partition created on laptop with Windows 11 and Pop OS

Tags: partition, disk, gparted, pop-os

I was using Windows 11 on my laptop but I wanted to install a Linux distro on the side.
Therefore, I've shrunk 30GB of the OS disk and I installed Pop_Os. During the installation process, I've created a EFI and root partitions.

I now wanted to extend the ext4 partition. I was able to shrink even more the original OS disk, but the unallocated space is shown on the left when using gParted and I'm unable to resize the root partition.

Below the gparted screenshots and fdisk outputs:

[image: gparted screenshot]

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476,94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: WDC PC SN520 SDAPMUW-512G-1101          
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 68C5B02D-2F6D-464B-AC15-BC33272E2AD7

Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    534528     567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    567296  761978879 761411584 363,1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 998166528 1000214527   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 939532288  996937725  57405438  27,4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p6 996937728  998166525   1228798   600M EFI System

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Getting a bit out my comfort zone now :)
How should I proceed now to expand the partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the resize from a LiveCD -- the `nvme0n1p5` partition is currently mounted. Ext4 can be resized when mounted, but only to the right -- resizing it to the left actually means copying/moving the data to the start of the free space and then resizing the partition and that cannot be done with an active (mounted) partition. So boot from a LiveCD (the Pop installation CD has GParted so you can use that) and use the GParted *Resize/Move* option to resize the partition. Don't forget to make a backup first.

Comment: It worked. thanks for the help! I didn't do any backup because it was a clean install so there would not be any issues if I lost the data, but no problem happened so even better.